# How to add vibration in timer app in flutter

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, timer

I am using flutter and I want the phone to vibrate when the timer is over. Any ideas on how I can do that?

Answer (score 0):

Use timer, and when it's done,use this package to vibrate: https://pub.dev/packages/vibration

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping with this......Also, could you recommend a good tutorial for learning SQLite in flutter